# Graphics3D with projected/flat eye view?

Tags: function-construction, graphics3d, options

Following image can be perceived as a cube (a regular hexagon with 3 internal line segments) :

[image]

But in mathematica, it is not possible to make such shape with rotation.

Examples of some close state of the above image by rotating cubes are :

[image] or
[image]

But we cannot adjust(rotation by mouse dragging) the `Graphics3D[Cube[]]` to fit in the regular hexagon.

So how can I generate **the first image like view** from `Graphics3D` and `Cube[]`.
I don't know what the appropriate term for this is.
Projected view method? Flat eye view method?

And if such a view method is possible, then I hope options like ViewVertical or ViewPoint can be adjusted while keeping such viewing method.

Comment: `ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"`

Comment: Thank you for fast answer!